# CouchDB SSL handshake error

Tags: ssl, erlang, couchdb

I've installed CouchDB on the mac via Homebrew (yay homebrew!):

```
brew install couchdb
```

Then I've done a bunch of SSL setup steps (in a shell script) that are detailed in the official documentation: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/config/http.html -

```
#!/bin/sh
currDir=$(pwd)
mkdir couch_certs
cd couch_certs
openssl genrsa > privkey.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -key privkey.pem -out couchdb.pem -days 1095
chmod 600 privkey.pem couchdb.pem
perl -p -i -e "s#\[daemons\]#[daemons]\nhttpsd = {couch_httpd, start_link,     [https]}#" /usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini
perl -p -i -e "s#\[ssl\]#[ssl]\ncert_file = ${currDir}/couchdb.pem#" /usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini
perl -p -i -e "s#\[ssl\]#[ssl]\nkey_file = ${currDir}/privkey.pem#" /usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini
```

Then (same terminal), I launch couch:

```
couchdb
```

In a different terminal I test that:

```
curl -k https://127.0.0.1:6984/
```

And get a failure:

```
curl: (35) Server aborted the SSL handshake
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note I can get the same error when doing the CouchDB install as an application (section 2.3.1 of http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/install/mac.html)

Edit: I think it is an Erlang SSL issue: http://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-74

Comment: The default port number is 5984, unless you've changed that in config somewhere that might be a problem.

Comment: 5984 is the default for http, 6984 for https, Dominic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My root cause was an older version of openssl (the one that came with OS X 10.10.5). After a homebrew install of openssl, and the same key-gen sequence, it all works.